# Wikimedia template doesn't rendered as expected?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

I just installed wikimedia on my server, and found out that the templates don't rendered as expected.

For example, `{{In use}}`

In [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:In_use), `{{In use}}` will be rendered into [image], which is I expect.

But on my server, `{{In use}}`yields

[image]

And so do the other templates. What I have to do so the templates can be shown properly?

Answer (score 2):

Templates are not built in. You have to import the templates from another wiki, e.g. [Wikia Templates](http://templates.wikia.com/wiki/Wikia_Templates) (less obfuscated than from Wikipedia), or [write them yourself](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Templates). You can't simply copy/paste templates. If you want a fully functional MW wiki they're an enormous headache.

Here's a helpful blog post on [how to import Wikipedia Templates into your own MediaWiki](http://www.ryadel.com/en/how-to-add-wikipedia-mbox-templates-to-your-own-mediawiki/).

Comment: I see. Guess I need to spend some time to study about the Wiki templates